# Acceleration in inclined and horizontal plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

[image]

If I apply the formula : $v^2=u^2+2$ as in the inclined plane, I get $a=0.87 ~\rm m/s^2$...
If I do the same thing in a horizontal plane (not inclined),the same result pops out...

I want to know what are the difference between these two results?

If acceleration in the inclined plane is effective acceleration, then why is it equal to the acceleration in the horizontal plane(not inclined)?

Comment: It is not clear what your exercise is. It could be . A difference will be clear considering the difference F required to do both with the same acceleration

Comment: @Alchimista my query is about the difference in acceleration of horizontal and inclined plane and the cause behind it...

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Alchimista Fcos 5° is not necessary in the inclined plane...here, mgsin5° acts downwards...so it is necessary to give a force more than that to accelerate it...

Comment: Ojk is matter of complete the forces diagram. I do not see what is the question here. Probably the exercise ask for the F needed in the two cases. From kinematics OP cannot discern the two cases.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. The 1st and 3rd sentences of your question say you get the *same* acceleration ("the same result pops out"). Your 2nd sentence and your comment ask about the *difference* in acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right, then you need to go from a specific start speed to a specific end speed in a specific distance.

**This requires a specific acceleration.**

It doesn't matter which way this motion happens. It's doesn't matter which things are pulling or pushing or grabbing or holding back. They just must result in **that specific acceleration**.

In other words:

- On a horizontal surface, you need **that specific acceleration** in order to reach that end speed over that distance. The car can exert a force to cause this acceleration, because nothing else holds back.
- On the inclined surface, you *still* need **that specific acceleration** in order to reach that end speed over that distance. Now gravity pulls backwards, so the car must exert *a larger* force in order for the car to reach **that same acceleration**.

Forces are different in different situations, because what holds back and what helps along in the motion may differ. But the motion we are aiming to reach, in this case acceleration, is the same regardless of how it is reached.

---

If you are not convinced, then consider this simpler example: Let's say that I am driving with a speed of $1\;\mathrm{m/s}$ and I want to speed up to $3\;\mathrm{m/s}$ *in 1 second*.

What is the acceleration I need to have? Simple: I need to accelerate with **$2\;\mathrm{m/s}$ per second**. $a=2\;\mathrm{m/s^2}$.

This is regardless of **the cause** of this acceleration. In other words: This is regardless of **the forces**. The forces acting - whichever they may be - just must result in this acceleration. Otherwise I will not reach the $3\;\mathrm{m/s}$ in one second. If I am driving upwards, then I must therefor exert a larger force in order to overcome gravity, **so the total force still is enough to cause that acceleration of $a=2\;\mathrm{m/s^2}$**.

Bottom line: Kinematics (the motion) can be considered separately from dynamics (the forces). Dynamics is the *cause of changes* in the kinematics. You can easily consider *how* something moves (it's position, speed, acceleration etc.) without thinking about *why* it has that acceleration.